# How to calculate: $\int k dt$

Tags: integration

This is a very simple integral:

$\int k dt$

But how would you evaluate it as we are integrating with respect to t, but the variable in the integrand is k?

The answer is kt+c, but why?

Comment: The answer may lie in something you haven't exaplined. What exactly is $k$

Comment: The k is just being used a constant multiplier from a direct proportions question.

Comment: So if $k$ is a constant number, then the integral becomes a matter of integrating a number. For example if $k=5$, then you just need to integrate $5$ with respect to $t$. So what differentiates to give you $5$? Or more generally, what differentiates to give you $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ is just a constant inside the integral, so
$$\int k \ dt = k\int dt$$
and the integral of $dt$ is the same as
$$\int 1\ dt =t+c$$
for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you differentiate with respect to $t$, what you get is $k$.